# Facebook login button appearing on page

Tags: html, facebook

I'm taking the tutorial for the FB login button. I'm straight-up copying and pasting the code (, so I can't figure out why it's not working. Instead, I'm just getting a comment "// The JS SDK Login Button" for some reason.

I'm especially confused because it was working for a while, until I tried to modify it. I broke it somehow, then cut out everything and started over from scratch. But this version isn't working. I did everything the same as the first time, so I'm pretty confused.

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<script>

  function statusChangeCallback(response) {  // Called with the results from FB.getLoginStatus().
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);                   // The current login status of the person.
    if (response.status === 'connected') {   // Logged into your webpage and Facebook.
      testAPI();
    } else {                                 // Not logged into your webpage or we are unable to tell.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this webpage.';
    }
  }


  function checkLoginState() {               // Called when a person is finished with the Login Button.
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {   // See the onlogin handler
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }


  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '1560520617436290',
      cookie     : true,                     // Enable cookies to allow the server to access the session.
      xfbml      : true,                     // Parse social plugins on this webpage.
      version    : '5.0'           // Use this Graph API version for this call.
    });


    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {   // Called after the JS SDK has been initialized.
      statusChangeCallback(response);        // Returns the login status.
    });
  };


  (function(d, s, id) {                      // Load the SDK asynchronously
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


  function testAPI() {                      // Testing Graph API after login.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
  }

</script>


//  The JS SDK Login Button

<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>

<div id="status">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The “comment” is just _text_ in the body part of your HTML document here, so it gets shown as-is. // Start by checking what the browser console has to say.

Comment: Hey! Right, I'm not confused about why the comment appears, I understand that it's text. My confusion is why the Facebook button (fb:login-button) does NOT appear:

Comment: Check what the browser console has to say.

Comment: It's not saying anything new --- that's mainly why I'm confused